# How many simultaneous/consecutive connections can an ESP8266 Webserver handle?

Tags: websocket, arduino, webserver, client-server, esp8266

So I'm using the **ESP8266WebServer** and **ESP8266WiFiMulti** libraries to run a webpage with **websockets** and I'm trying to figure out how many client connections I can have, and if there's any way to increase that connection limit?

Right now it seems that I can successfully create **three** connections from **separate IPs**, and then upon initiating the **fourth** connection, it fails (the server doesn't crash in the serial model, but the fourth connection won't load the webpage).

I've also noticed that if I refresh my own **singular** connection a certain number of times **(inconsistent)**, it will fail to load the webpage as well. I haven't been able to decipher whether this has to do with there being **too many consecutive connections** in general or if I'm **overtaxing the server** by attempting to reconnect within too quick a timeframe?

In general though, it seems rather **unstable** and I could really use some assistance on figuring out why.

Here's my current code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include <Hash.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

static const char ssid[] = "********";
static const char password[] = "********";
MDNSResponder mdns;

static void writeLED(bool);

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

IPAddress ipAddressTest = (99,99,99,99);

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(81);

uint8_t pageHitCounter = 0;
IPAddress ipAddressOne = (99,99,99,99); 
IPAddress ipAddressTwo = (99,99,99,99); 
IPAddress ipAddressThree = (99,99,99,99); 
IPAddress ipAddressFour = (99,99,99,99); 

uint8_t rxBuff[256];
uint8_t som = 0x11; 
uint8_t eom = 0x12; 
uint8_t subsys; 
uint8_t receivedSubsys;
uint8_t rx_byte = 0x00;
uint8_t messageLength = 0;
uint8_t receivedMessageLength = 0;
uint8_t messageContent;
uint8_t serialCurrent; 

int initialCounter = 0;
boolean messageBegun = false; 
boolean messageInProgress = false;

int currNumRefresh = 0;
int currMicroC = 0;
int currMicroD = 0;
int currMicroE = 0;
int currPressureC = 0; 
int currPressureD = 0; 
int currPressureE = 0; 
int currValveStatusNumC = 0; 
int currValveStatusNumD = 0; 
int currValveStatusNumE = 0;
int currFluid = 0;

char statusbuf[256]; 
char status[] = "";
int statusIndex = 0;

String valveStatusC = "Closed";
String valveTubePropsC = "175px solid #00ADEF";
String valveColorC = "red";

String valveStatusD = "Closed";
String valveTubePropsD = "175px solid #00ADEF";
String valveColorD = "red";

String valveStatusE = "Closed";
String valveTubePropsE = "175px solid #00ADEF";
String valveColorE = "red";

uint8_t currCountdown = 0;
long prevTimeCountdown = 0; 
long countdownInterval = 1000; 
long countdownPostInterval = 100;
bool countdownFlag = true;

bool teensyPOWER = false;
bool pumpPOWER = false;
bool teensyLED = false;

void switchPOWERon() {

//Serial.println("TEST POWER ON");

int powerStatusLength = 1;

subsys = 0x10; 

//Account for the end of message
messageLength = powerStatusLength + 2;

messageContent = 1;

Serial.write(som);
Serial.write(messageLength);
Serial.write(subsys);
Serial.write(messageContent);
Serial.write(eom);
//Serial.println("");
//Serial.println("TURN POWER ON|");
//teensyLED = true;
} //end switchPOWERon

void switchPOWERoff() {
/*Very similar to switchPoweron(), removed for char space*/
} //end switchPOWERoff

void pumpPOWERon() {

//Serial.println("TEST POWER ON");

int pumpPowerStatusLength = 1;

subsys = 0x13; 

//Account for the end of message
messageLength = pumpPowerStatusLength + 2;

messageContent = 1;

Serial.write(som);
Serial.write(messageLength);
Serial.write(subsys);
Serial.write(messageContent);
Serial.write(eom);
//Serial.println("");
//Serial.println("TURN POWER ON|");
//teensyLED = true;
} //end switchPOWERon

void pumpPOWERoff() {

/*Very similar to pumpPoweron(), removed for char space*/
} //end switchPOWERoff

void switchLEDon() {

//Serial.println("TEST LED ON");

int ledStatusLength = 1;

subsys = 0x14; 

//Account for the end of message
messageLength = ledStatusLength + 2;

messageContent = 1;

Serial.write(som);
Serial.write(messageLength);
Serial.write(subsys);
Serial.write(messageContent);
Serial.write(eom);
//Serial.println("");
//Serial.println("TURN LED ON|");
//teensyLED = true;
} //end switchLEDon

void switchLEDoff() {

/*Very similar to switchLEDon(), removed for char space*/
} //end switchLEDoff

void statusUpdate(uint8_t num) {

//Valve C
if(currValveStatusNumC == 0)
{
    valveColorC = "red";
    valveTubePropsC = "175px solid #00ADEF";
    valveStatusC = "Closed";
} //end if
else if(currValveStatusNumC == 1)
{
    valveColorC = "green";
    valveTubePropsC = "350px solid #00ADEF"; 
    valveStatusC = "Open";
} //end else if

/*Valves D/E removed for char space, very similar to Valve C*/

String test = ""; 
test += currNumRefresh;
test += ",";
/*Preparing more variables to send to the webpage, removed for char space*/
test += ",";
test += ipAddressTest;

//Serial.print("TEST: ");
//Serial.println(ipAddressTest);

test.toCharArray(statusbuf, 256);
webSocket.sendTXT(num, statusbuf, strlen(statusbuf));
}

static const char PROGMEM INDEX_HTML[] = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Adafruit HUZZAH ESP8266</title>

<style type='text/css'>   
/*CSS removed to fit maximum number of allowed characters*/
</style>
<script>

var currPressureTest = 0;
var currFluidTest = 0;                                               

function POWERswitch(){
var POWERswitchCheck = document.getElementById('switch1').checked;        

if(POWERswitchCheck){
    websock.send("teensyPOWERon");      
}
else if(!POWERswitchCheck) {
    websock.send("teensyPOWERoff");
}
}

function FLUSHbegin(){
websock.send("pumpPOWERon");            
}

function FLUSHend(){
websock.send("pumpPOWERoff");
}

function LEDswitch(){
var LEDswitchCheck = document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked;        

if(LEDswitchCheck){
    websock.send("teensyLEDon");      
}
else if(!LEDswitchCheck) {
    websock.send("teensyLEDoff");
}
}

var websock;
var test = "open";
var webpageHitCounter = 20; 

function start() {
websock = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':81/');
websock.onopen = function(evt) { 
    console.log('websock open'); 
    statusUpdate();
};
websock.onclose = function(evt) { 
    console.log('websock close'); 
};
websock.onerror = function(evt) { 
    console.log(evt); 
};
websock.onmessage = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    var e = document.getElementById('ledstatus');
    var te = document.getElementById('myonoffswitch');
    var pe = document.getElementById('switch1');


    if(evt.data === 'teensyPOWERon')
    {
        pe.checked = 'checked';
    }
    else if(evt.data === 'teensyPOWERoff')
    {
        pe.checked = '';
    }
    else if(evt.data === 'pumpPOWERon')
    {

    }
    else if(evt.data === 'pumpPOWERoff')
    {

    }
    else if(evt.data === 'teensyLEDon')
    {
        te.checked = 'checked';
    }
    else if(evt.data === 'teensyLEDoff')
    {
        te.checked = '';
    }
    else if(evt.data === 'Update Status')
    {

    }
    else {
      console.log('status event');

      var totalStatus = evt.data;                                              
      var splitStatus = totalStatus.split(',');                                                                                     

      //Num Refresh
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = splitStatus[0];                 

      /*Setting more variables from splitStatus[], removed for char space*/

      }
  };
  }

  function statusUpdate() {
  websock.send("Update Status");
  setTimeout('statusUpdate()', 5000);  
  }

    </script>                  
</head>

<body style='background-color:#4a4a4c;' onload="start();">

    <div style='text-align:center;'>
        <h1 style='text-decoration: underline; color:white;'>Adafruit HUZZAH ESP8266</h1>
    </div>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>     

    <div class='counterContainer'>
        <span id="counterText" style="color:white;"></span>
    </div>

    <div id='adminControls' class='adminControlsRow'>

        <h2>Administrator Controls</h2>

        <div id='Newbtn' class='powerSwitchContainer'>
            <h2>HHIO PTT Power</h2>

            <span class="switch">
               <span class="switch-border1">
                    <span class="switch-border2">
                       <input id="switch1" type="checkbox" onclick='POWERswitch()' checked />
                       <label for="switch1"></label>
                       <span class="switch-top"></span>
                       <span class="switch-shadow"></span>
                       <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                       <span class="switch-handle-left"></span>
                       <span class="switch-handle-right"></span>
                       <span class="switch-handle-top"></span>
                       <span class="switch-handle-bottom"></span>
                       <span class="switch-handle-base"></span>
                       <span class="switch-led switch-led-green">
                          <span class="switch-led-border">
                             <span class="switch-led-light">
                                <span class="switch-led-glow"></span>
                             </span>
                          </span>
                       </span>
                       <span class="switch-led switch-led-red">
                          <span class="switch-led-border">
                            <span class="switch-led-light">
                                <span class="switch-led-glow"></span>
                             </span>
                          </span>
                       </span>
                    </span>
               </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class='flushBtnContainer'>
            <h2>Fluid Reservoir</h2>
            <button id='flushBtn' onmousedown="FLUSHbegin();" onmouseup="FLUSHend();">Flush</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style='background-color:#1E1E20; clear:both;'>
        <h2 style='color: white;'>LED Controls</h2>                            
        <div id='LEDbtn' class='onoffswitch'>                             
            <input type='checkbox' name='onoffswitch' class='onoffswitch-checkbox' id='myonoffswitch' onclick='LEDswitch()'>                            
            <label class='onoffswitch-label' for='myonoffswitch'>
                <span class='onoffswitch-inner'></span>
                <span class='onoffswitch-switch'></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>              

    <div style='background-color:#1E1E20; color: white;'>
        <h2>Num Refresh Test</h2>    
        <div id="demo"><h2>Let WEBSOCKET change this text</h2></div>
    </div>

    <div class='headerRow'>
        /*Headers removed for char space*/
    </div>

    <div class='microswitchRow'>
        <div class="microswitchContainer">
          <div class="microswitch white">
             <input type="radio" name="switchC" class="microswitchRadio" id="switchOffC" checked>
             <input type="radio" name="switchC" class="microswitchRadio" id="switchOnC">

             <label for="switchOffC">Detached</label>
             <label for="switchOnC">Attached</label>

             <span class="toggle"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="microswitchContainer">
          <div class="microswitch white">
             <input type="radio" name="switchD" class="microswitchRadio" id="switchOffD" checked>
             <input type="radio" name="switchD" class="microswitchRadio" id="switchOnD">

             <label for="switchOffD">Detached</label>
             <label for="switchOnD">Attached</label>

             <span class="toggle"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="microswitchContainer">
          <div class="microswitch white">
             <input type="radio" name="switchE" class="microswitchRadio" id="switchOffE" checked>
             <input type="radio" name="switchE" class="microswitchRadio" id="switchOnE">

             <label for="switchOffE">Detached</label>
             <label for="switchOnE">Attached</label>

             <span class="toggle"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='pressureRow'>
        <div class='pressureContainer'>
            <div class='gauge-a'></div>
            <div class='gauge-b'></div>
            <div class='gauge-c'></div>
            <div class='gauge-data'><h1 id='pressurePercentC'>0%</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class='pressureContainer'>
            <div class='gauge-a'></div>
            <div class='gauge-b'></div>
            <div class='gauge-d'></div>
            <div class='gauge-data'><h1 id='pressurePercentD'>0%</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class='pressureContainer'>
            <div class='gauge-a'></div>
            <div class='gauge-b'></div>
            <div class='gauge-e'></div>
            <div class='gauge-data'><h1 id='pressurePercentE'>0%</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>           

    <div class='valveRow'>
        <div class='valveContainer'>
            <div class="valveTube-c"></div>
            <div class="valve-c"></div>
            <div class='valve-data'><h1 id='valveStatus-c'>Closed</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class='valveContainer'>
            <div class="valveTube-d"></div>
            <div class="valve-d"></div>
            <div class='valve-data'><h1 id='valveStatus-d'>Closed</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class='valveContainer'>
            <div class="valveTube-e"></div>
            <div class="valve-e"></div>
            <div class='valve-data'><h1 id='valveStatus-e'>Closed</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='fluidContainer'>
        <meter class='fluidMeter' max='100' value='50' low='25' high='75' optimum='100'></meter> 
        <div class='fluid-data'><h1 id='fluidPercent'>0%</h1></div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
)rawliteral";

const int LEDPIN = 0;

// Current POWER status
bool POWERStatus;

// Current LED status
bool LEDStatus;

// Commands sent through Web Socket
/*command array declarations removed for char space*/

const char statusIdentifier[] = "Update Status";

void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length)
{
  //Serial.printf("webSocketEvent(%d, %d, ...)\r\n", num, type);
  switch(type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
  //Serial.printf("[%u] Disconnected!\r\n", num);
  break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
  {
    IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
    //Serial.printf("[%u] Connected from %d.%d.%d.%d url: %s\r\n", num, ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3], payload);

    // Send the current LED status
    if (LEDStatus) {
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, LEDON, strlen(LEDON));
    }
    else if(!LEDStatus) {
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, LEDOFF, strlen(LEDOFF));
    }
    else if(teensyPOWER) {
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, teensyPOWERON, strlen(teensyPOWERON));
    }
    else if(!teensyPOWER) {
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, teensyPOWEROFF, strlen(teensyPOWEROFF));
    }  
    else if(pumpPOWER) {
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, teensyPOWERON, strlen(teensyPOWERON));
    }
    else if(!pumpPOWER) {
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, pumpPOWEROFF, strlen(pumpPOWEROFF));
    }  
    else if(teensyLED) {
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, teensyLEDON, strlen(teensyLEDON));
    }
    else if(!teensyLED) {
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, teensyLEDOFF, strlen(teensyLEDOFF));
    }
  }
  break;
case WStype_TEXT:
  //Serial.printf("[%u] get Text: %s\r\n", num, payload);

  if (strcmp(LEDON, (const char *)payload) == 0) {
    writeLED(true);
  }
  else if (strcmp(LEDOFF, (const char *)payload) == 0) {
    writeLED(false);
  }
  else if(strcmp(teensyPOWERON,  (const char *)payload) == 0) {
      switchPOWERon();
  }
  else if(strcmp(teensyPOWEROFF,  (const char *)payload) == 0) {
      switchPOWERoff();
  }
  else if(strcmp(pumpPOWERON,  (const char *)payload) == 0) {
      pumpPOWERon();
  }
  else if(strcmp(pumpPOWEROFF,  (const char *)payload) == 0) {
      pumpPOWERoff();
  } 
  else if(strcmp(teensyLEDON,  (const char *)payload) == 0) {
      switchLEDon();
  }
  else if(strcmp(teensyLEDOFF,  (const char *)payload) == 0) {
      switchLEDoff();
  }
  else if(strcmp(statusIdentifier, (const char *)payload) == 0) {
      statusUpdate(num);
  }
  else {
    //Serial.println("Unknown command");
  }
  // send data to all connected clients
  webSocket.broadcastTXT(payload, length);
  break;
case WStype_BIN:
  //Serial.printf("[%u] get binary length: %u\r\n", num, length);
  hexdump(payload, length);

  // echo data back to browser
  webSocket.sendBIN(num, payload, length);
  break;
default:
  //Serial.printf("Invalid WStype [%d]\r\n", type);
  break;
  }
}

void handleRoot()
{

  server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);

  if(ipAddressTest != (0,0,0,0))
  {
  if(ipAddressOne == (99,99,99,99))
  {
      ipAddressOne = ipAddressTest;
      pageHitCounter++;
      //server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);

      Serial.print("1st NEW IP: ");
      Serial.println(ipAddressTest);
      }

      else if(ipAddressTwo == (99,99,99,99))
      {
      if(ipAddressOne == ipAddressTest)
      {
          Serial.print("Old Connection-1 currently connected; Current Connection: ");
          Serial.println(ipAddressTest);
          //server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);
      }
      else
      {
          ipAddressTwo = ipAddressTest;
          pageHitCounter++;
          //server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);

          Serial.print("2nd NEW IP: ");
          Serial.println(ipAddressTest);
      }
      }

      else if(ipAddressThree == (99,99,99,99)) 
      {
      if(ipAddressOne == ipAddressTest || ipAddressTwo == ipAddressTest)
      {
           Serial.print("Old Connection-2 currently connected; Current Connection: ");
           Serial.println(ipAddressTest);
           //server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);
      }
      else
      {
          ipAddressThree = ipAddressTest;
          pageHitCounter++;
          //server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);

          Serial.print("3rd NEW IP: ");
          Serial.println(ipAddressTest);
      }
      }

      else if(ipAddressFour == (99,99,99,99))
      {
      if(ipAddressOne == ipAddressTest || ipAddressTwo == ipAddressTest || ipAddressThree == ipAddressTest)
      {
           Serial.println("Old Connection-3 currently connected; Current Connection: ");
           Serial.println(ipAddressTest);
           //server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);
      }
      else
      {
          ipAddressFour = ipAddressTest;
          pageHitCounter++;
          //server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);

          Serial.print("4th NEW IP: ");
          Serial.println(ipAddressTest);
      }
      }

      else
      {
      if(ipAddressOne == ipAddressTest || ipAddressTwo == ipAddressTest || ipAddressThree == ipAddressTest || ipAddressFour == ipAddressTest)
      {
           Serial.println("Old Connection-4 currently connected; Current Connection: ");
           Serial.println(ipAddressTest);
           //server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);
      }
      else
      {
          Serial.print("Too many connections! Attempting to Connect: ");
          Serial.println(ipAddressTest);
      }
      }
  }



}

void handleNotFound()
{
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++){
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}

static void writeLED(bool LEDon)
{
  LEDStatus = LEDon;
  // Note inverted logic for Adafruit HUZZAH board
  if (LEDon) {
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, 0);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, 1);
  }
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
  writeLED(false);

  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  currCountdown = 4; 

  for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {

unsigned long currTime = millis();

if(countdownFlag == true)
{
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\r\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    countdownFlag = false; 
}


if(currTime - prevTimeCountdown > countdownInterval)
{
    prevTimeCountdown = currTime; 
    countdownFlag = true; 
} //end if

else
{
    t++;
} //end else

  } //end for

  WiFiMulti.addAP(ssid, password);
/*
  prevTimeCountdown = 0;
  countdownFlag = true;
*/   
  while(WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  /*
  unsigned long currTime = millis();

  if(countdownFlag == true)
  {
      Serial.print(".");
      countdownFlag = false; 
  } //end if

  if(currTime - prevTimeCountdown > countdownInterval)
  {
      prevTimeCountdown = currTime; 
      countdownFlag = true; 
  } //end if
  */
  Serial.print(".");
  delay(1000);

  } //end while

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (mdns.begin("espWebSock", WiFi.localIP())) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
    mdns.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
    mdns.addService("ws", "tcp", 81);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("MDNS.begin failed");
  }
  Serial.print("Connect to http://espWebSock.local or http://");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();

  webSocket.begin();
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
    }

void loop()
{
//Communication Protocol
if(Serial.available() > 0)
{
    //Serial.print("SERIAL.AVAILABLE: ");
    //Serial.println(Serial.available());

    if(initialCounter == 0)
    {
        rx_byte = Serial.read();
    /*
        //Print Start of Message
        Serial.print("0x");
        if(rx_byte<0x10)
        {
            Serial.print("0");
        }
        Serial.println(rx_byte, HEX);
    */
        //Serial.println(rx_byte, BIN);
        //Serial.println(rx_byte);

        initialCounter++;
    }


    if((!messageBegun) && (rx_byte == som))
    {
        messageBegun = true;

        //Serial.println("MESSAGE BEGUN TRUE");
    } //end if (messageInProgress && rx_byte)

    if((messageBegun) && (!messageInProgress))
    {
        serialCurrent = Serial.available();

        if(serialCurrent > 0)
        {      
            receivedMessageLength = (uint8_t)Serial.read();
        /*
            Serial.print("MESSAGE LENGTH: ");
            Serial.println(receivedMessageLength);
        */
            messageBegun = false;

            messageInProgress = true;

            //Serial.println("MESSAGE IN PROGRESS TRUE");

        } //end if (serialCurrent)
    } //end if (messageBegun && messageInProgress)

    if(messageInProgress)
    {
        serialCurrent = Serial.available(); 

        if(serialCurrent >= receivedMessageLength)
        {

            Serial.readBytes(rxBuff, receivedMessageLength);

            if((byte)rxBuff[receivedMessageLength-1] != eom)
            {
                //Serial.println("ERROR");
                //Serial.write(Serial.read());
            } //end if (rxBuff != eom)

            else
            {
                messageInProgress = false; 

                for(int i=0; i<receivedMessageLength; i++)
                {
                    if(rxBuff[i] == eom)
                    {
                    /*
                        //Print End of Message
                        Serial.print("0x");
                        if(rx_byte<0x10)
                        {
                            Serial.print("0");
                        }
                        Serial.println(rxBuff[i], HEX);
                    */
                        initialCounter = 0;

                        receivedMessageLength = 0;

                    } //end if

                    else if(i == 0)
                    {
                        receivedSubsys = rxBuff[i]; 
                    /*
                        //Print Subsystem
                        Serial.print("0x");
                        if(rx_byte<0x10)
                        {
                            Serial.print("0");
                        }
                        Serial.println(rxBuff[i], HEX);
                    */
                    } //end if
                    else
                    {
                        if(receivedSubsys == 0x14)
                        {
                            currNumRefresh = rxBuff[i];
                        } //end if

                        /*Other subsystems removed for char space*/
            } //end else

        } //end if (serialCurrent)

    } //end if (messageInProgress)
} //end if (Serial.available)

  webSocket.loop();
  ipAddressTest = server.handleClient();
}
```

P.S. I slightly modified **ESP8266WebServer.cpp's handleClient()** function to return the current IP address in order to track individual users, however sometimes I get **0.0.0.0** as an IP address and I don't know why or how to tell if that IP is a new IP or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I seem to have solved the issue by using the FS.h library and having an actual filesystem with directories where I can have actual html/css/js files and what not. This seems to have solved the stability issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think Espressif documentation suggests a max of 5 UDP/TCP connections, that's what everyone always mentions anyways. I'd look it up but I'm behind a firewall right now :)

You don't mention which environment you are using, but I'm guessing Arduino based.

I don't know why you hit a limit at 3 instead of 5, could it be you're using connections for other protocols? I'm not sure what the MDNS stuff does, so maybe something in that. Also your browser could possibly be opening more connections then you expect (debug with browser debug functionality, e.g. f12? on most).

As usual, minimizing your code to the smallest example will help, try just the webserver, and see if you get closer to 5 :)

Comment: So I looked into this a little more after I posted this and discovered that it appeared to be because of the websocket code that I've been using. 

After that I researched some more and realized that while I've been storing my entire webpage in a string, there's a far better way to do this by using the FS.h library and having an actual filesystem with directories where I can have actual html/css/js files and what not. 

That seemed to solve the stability issues, and now I've been facing a new problem.

Comment: I'm using a serial connection between a teensy 3.1 and this ESP8266, however it seems that the ESP8266 has to be powered on before the teensy, otherwise it won't work (this includes whenever the ESP8266 restarts, it breaks the serial connection or something and so I always have to unplug/plug back in the teensy as well). 

I think it has something to do with my Serial1.begin() command on the teensy because if I add a delay in the setup() before that to give the wifi card time to set up it works fine.

Comment: To be more specific, yes I'm using an Arduino based environment, and I'm not actually hosting my own access point off the ESP8266, but merely serving a webpage to another already existing access point.

Comment: Hmm, wild guess, could it be a baud rate thing? When the ESP is booting it's cpu speed is 26mhz, resulting in 74880 baud, when it clocks up later to 40mhz you get 115200. I know nothing about teensy, does it autosense the baud rate, can you force it to 115200? :)

Comment: Well considering when I set up the connection, I use the same kind of command: Serial1.begin(115200); ...I think I'm forcing it like you're saying?

Comment: I think the problem is that for some reason the connection on the teensy has to be set up AFTER the connection on the ESP8266, and so do you know if there would be a way to trigger a reinitialization of the teensy's serial connection after it has begun? I tried reusing the Serial1.begin() command but that doesn't appear to work?

Comment: I've tried putting this in the loop, but it's not working :(

if(!Serial1)
    {
        Serial1.end();
        Serial1.begin(115200);
    } //end if

Comment: Another new thing I've noticed...it only breaks the receiving connection from the ESP8266, the teensy still transmits information to the ESP8266, but nothing is getting sent to the teensy.

Answer (score 1):

you must be careful with the size of the files you upload with FS.h. depending on the size some problems are generated when generating the page

Comment: Do you know the size limitations?

Comment: I do not think there is a defined maximum size, but as the size increases, example files 30Kb, the page begins to take 8, 10, 15 seconds to load and some of them are not fully loaded with text files, are recommends compress (* .gz).
I had problems with pictures of 7Kb size, (5 files) do not load all the images.

When are files (* .css) what I do is to include within the index.htm and the best I have if no images, including the index.htm in the sketch. This will load much faster than with fs.h

Comment: Well unfortunately I need to include libraries like jquery and what not so doing this without fs.h I think is kind of impossible for me. 

Here's the new thread I made if you can assist at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711762/issue-loading-files-w-spiffs-err-content-length-mismatch